# Points from Sprite.graphics in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to know where the `Sprite.graphics` start to do some stuff. When I add the sprite to my MovieClip, `(x,y)` coordinates are `(0,0)` but I need to know coordinates from `Sprite.graphics`, not `Sprite`. There are some images so clarify what I want:

[image]

I have this board where user can draw some forms (lines, arrows, polygons, etc.) When the user draw a line, I interpret that `Sprite` is created (with `Sprite.graphics` inside it, the real form).

[image]

How can I catch the point where `Sprite.graphics` is created? Actually I can't because `Sprite.graphics` is read-only.

Thanks!

EDIT: some source code

```
line = new Sprite();
line.graphics.moveTo(posX,posY);
line.graphics.lineStyle(10);
line.graphics.lineTo(endposX,endposY);
Global.board.addChild(line);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you you trying to do. I'm guessing that you want to know the position of the origin of the line drawn by the user? You already know this, since you're drawing the line. In your code, its `posX` and `posY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the bounds of visual part, you can try:

```
var bounds: Rectangle = line.getBounds(line);
```

There is also a getRect() method, but that leaves out space taken by strokes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the graphics data like that. Your best chance would be to save the coordinates `posX` and `posY` yourself when the line is being drawn.